# Qt/PyQt: How do I use a QMenu as a permanent widget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I would like to use a QMenu as a permanent widget in the gui. (I like its appearance and layout, and the fact that as soon as I hover over it, the requisite menu pops up, no clicking needed. It would be a pain in the neck to try and emulate it with a custom widget.) I have tried adding it to a parent widget's layout, but after the first time it is used, it disappears. How would I go about keeping it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any option in `QMenu` that would disable auto-hide, so simplest way would be a subclass that overrides `hideEvent`. `hideEvent` is fired just before `hide()` completes. That means you can't intercept/ignore `hide()` but you can re-show it:

```
class PermanentMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    def hideEvent(self, event):
        self.show()
```

Just make your top-level menu from `PermanentMenu` and it should be fine.

A simple example using it:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class PermanentMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    def hideEvent(self, event):
        self.show()


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.menu = PermanentMenu()

        self.menu.addAction('one')
        self.menu.addAction('two')

        self.submenu = self.menu.addMenu('submenu')
        self.submenu.addAction('sub one')
        self.submenu.addAction('sub two')

        self.submenu2 = self.menu.addMenu('submenu 2')
        self.submenu2.addAction('sub 2 one')
        self.submenu2.addAction('sub 2 two')

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.menu)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Window()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Perfect. I'm just worried that it might end up flashing out and then back in during high cpu use, but so far I'm not seeing that.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, it's possible. Is there any reason for not using something like `QToolBar`?

Comment: Mostly because I want the menu to automatically appear when the mouse moves over it, not after a click. Is there a way to do that with a QToolBar?

Comment: @Jeff: Not by default. You'll need to subclass it, detect hover with `mouseMoveEvent` and act accordingly. It'll not be a trivial thing, for sure :).

Comment: This causes my app to freeze. Looks like an infinite loop.